# Gravity, connection, and curvature

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

Starting with Synge and Fock, many modern authors identify gravity with curvature. On the other hand, Einstein always emphasized that gravity should be equated with a connection, but not with curvature. For example, in a September 1950 letter to Max von Laue, Einstein explicitly stated that, from an empirical point of view, the presence of a gravitational field means that the Christoffel symbols are different from zero, and not the Riemann tensor (a fragment of the letter can be found in the article by J.J. Stachel, "How Einstein discovered general relativity: a historical tale with some contemporary morals"). 
Einstein’s position may seem a little strange, because, as Peter Havas noted in 1967, Christoffel’s symbols can be made non-zero simply by choosing curvilinear coordinates without any mention of an accelerated frame of reference. For me, the best definition, reconciling both positions, was given by Jürgen Ehlers in the "Survey of General Relativity Theory" https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-010-2639-0_1 "gravity is a non-integrable, symmetric connection, whose geodesics are the free fall trajectories".

An interesting argument showing that the curvature provides too narrow perspective on gravity was given by Kevin Brown (a mysterious author of excellent site MathPages https://www.mathpages.com/ ) in https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath622/kmath622.htm
he writes:

> It’s possible to arrange masses in such a way as to produce a situation such as shown in this figure. There is no doubt that this situation requires the existence of some curvature somewhere, but the interior region can be intrinsically flat, even though free objects in the interior accelerate relative to the flat exterior spacetime. Would we really say there is no gravitational field in the “flat” interior region? This shows that it is too simplistic to identify gravity with curvature. It is analogous to claiming an absolute distinction between electric and magnetic fields. The approach advocated by Einstein – regarding the metric tensor as both the gravitational and the inertial field, regardless of whether there is curvature at any given point – is much more intelligible.
>   [image]

I wonder if the space-time example shown in the figure has ever been explicitly constructed.

Comment: If your question is the final sentence: there are a few problems. (a) what does it mean to have "homogeneous acceleration relative to exterior Minkowski space-time? How is this any different from just choosing a weird coordinate system on the flat space-time where the coordinate system "travels" in the middle? (b) Unless you actually require an equation to be satisfied, in the smooth category you can write down pretty much any pseudo-Riemannian manifold you want. Do you actually mean you want a solution to Einstein's equation with an appropriate matter model that looks like your picture? (ctd)

Comment: ... If so, for any reasonable matter model your picture is ruled out by the positive mass theorem. (Flat on the exterior means automatically asymptotically flat, but reasonable matter model gives non-negative matter energy density, and so flat at infinity means globally flat.)

Comment: In Newtonian gravity if one has a spherical cavity inside a ball, the gravitational field is homogenous inside the cavity (Newtonian space-time is flat inside cavity). However outside the cavity gravitational field is not homogenous - Newtonian space-time is curved outside the cavity except at infinity where it becomes asymptotically flat. I'm asking whether something similar exists in general relativity.

Comment: Yes. But note that in the Newtonian picture you can just assume there exists a rigid shell of matter; in the Relativistic picture you have to think about an actual matter model and prove that the matter will not collapse under self gravitation. For certain hyperelastic matter you can have shells. https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0603103 The exterior metric is that of Schwarzschild.

Comment: If you are willing for the shell to be dynamics, then there are many solutions with fluid/dust matter in a shell with a flat interior. // final remark: the Newtonian spherical cavity has **0** gravitational field inside the cavity. It has homogeneous (constant) gravitational _potential_. But in any case I fail to see how these cases connect with the passage quoted from "MathPages" in yellow in your original post.

Comment: If the Newtonian spherical cavity is off-centered (its center doesn't coincide with the center of the ball), the gravitational field inside the cavity will be not zero (but homogeneous/constant).